# Invalid Siri Support - Sample phrase "example phrase here" was not classified as a INCreateTaskListIntent intent

Tags: ios, ios11, siri, sirikit

I am trying to implement SiriKit for iOS 11, specifically utilizing lists and notes. My AppIntentVocabulary.plist is shown below as a gist.

AppName replaces my App's real name.

https://gist.github.com/mitch2be/6e49d5e07e567bbc4d049bc565dad473

Each time I submit I get an email from iTunesConnect stating:

Invalid Siri Support - Sample phrase "Create new grocery list in AppName." was not classified as a INCreateTaskListIntent intent

Invalid Siri Support - Sample phrase "Add mik to my grocery list in AppName." was not classified as a INAddTasksIntent intent

There are more Invalid Siri Support messages for the other remaining sample phrases.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? Do the sample phrases needed to be implemented elsewhere?

The AppIntentVocabulary.plist has a target membership to the main app. I also added it to the SiriKit extension and tried it but that didn't work either.

Any thoughts or solutions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Same bug here, it drives me nuts

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: same issue here, seems to be a bug

Comment: Did anybody find a proper solution?

Comment: Same issue.....